# Questions that received a bounty aren't updated live

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, live-refresh

If questions have a bounty placed on them, they receive an activity bump that puts them on the front page again.

However, this bump isn't broadcast via the new realtime updates web socket voodoo, so people relying on it won't see the question until they refresh for real.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will happen after our next build.